# During aggregation creating key value pairs from properties in the same document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation

I have a document with several properties. For example

```js
{
    name: "Some name",
    business: "object-id",
    price: 10,
    category: "Some category",
}
```

During aggreation I am trying to match an object id for property business, then I am trying to group them by category to return an array. This array will contain an object for each category, and an array with an object that has key-value pairs using name -> price. Here is what I currently have:

```js
collection.aggregate([
        { $match: { business: ObjectId(req.params.businessId) } },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$category",

            }
        }
]).toArray()
```

I could not find how to generate the array with objects containing name -> price key value pairs. For example:

```js
[
    {_id: "a category", services: [{name:"service1", price:10}, {name:"service2", price:15}]},
    {_id: "second category", services: [{name:"service1", price:10}, {name:"service2", price:10}]}
    {_id: "third category", services: [{name:"service1", price:5}, {name:"service2", price:55}]}
]
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirement can be achieved by using the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) feature of mongodb.

```
collection.aggregate([
        { $match: { business: ObjectId(req.params.businessId) } },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$category",
                services: { $push:  { name: "$name", price: "$price" } }
            }
        }
]).toArray()
```